# Is There A Simple Equation For Calculating The Average Distance Between One Point In A Grid And Every Other Point?

Tags: linear-algebra, average

Say I have a rectangle/square grid made out of smaller squares; each square is 1 'unit' by 1 'unit' in size. The grid is *"w"* squares wide and *"h"* squares tall.

Now, let's say that I want to write, in every single square, the average of the distances between it's own center, and the center of every other square in the grid.

Say, for any given square, we refer to it's position as being *"x"* on the horizontal, and *"y"* on the vertical.

Knowing the values *"w"*, *"h"*, *"x"* and *"y"*, is there an equation that can allow me to quickly calculate the average distance to all the other squares? Or do I need to manually calculate every distance and then just average out the sum?

Even if someone could offer an equation that wasn't dead accurate, but good for rough estimates, I'd appreciate it.

*Edit:* At the moment, my best running theory is to average out the distances on each axis between the point and the edges of the grid. i.e.

$a = \frac{(\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{(w-x)^2}{2})}{w}$

$b = \frac{(\frac{y^2}{2} + \frac{(h-y)^2}{2})}{h}$

...and then calculate the hypotenuse for those averages, to get the overall grid average I'm looking for. Not sure if it holds up in practice, though.

Comment: I'm not sure there is an answer, but if there is it would be connected to the concept of mean field theory from physics. Because this problem is very similar to getting the gravitational potential of a massive particle in a grid of other massive particles. Except you want to average the distance instead of the reciprocal distance.

Comment: Have you tried Induction?

Comment: You can get a rough order of magnitude calculation in the following way. Draw rings of squares around your starting point within the grid, where the larger of the horizontal and vertical distances between the starting point and a point in the $i$th ring is $i$. Now the distance to points in the $i$th ring is between $i$ and $\sqrt{2} i$, the number of points in the $i$th ring is between $2i$ and $8i$, and there are between $n/2$ and $n$ rings. So I think the average on a square grid is between $n/3$ and $4\sqrt{2}n/3$.

Comment: You could do something kind of similar on a rectangular grid although the bounds would get even worse.